# GraphlQL Sortby argument is expecting comma

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql

Having an issue setting up a default sortBy for a graphQLList. I get this error in Visual Studio
"',' expected.ts(1005)". The error exactly appears on the full stop between args and sortBy. Does anyone know how to properly write this?

```
latestMovies: {
type: new GraphQLList(MovieType),
args: {
  limit: {type: GraphQLInt, defaultValue: 12},
  sortBy: {type: GraphQLString, defaultValue: "releaseDate: -1"}
},
resolve(parent, args) {
  return Movie.find({}).limit(args.limit).sort( { args.sortBy } );
},
```

}

Comment: `sortBy` string - really?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: bad sort() argument

Comment: Are you able to tell me how to fix?

Comment: hardcode it  - then you should know it is an complex object - use `sortBy` and `sortOrder` separately ... at start?